# In the category of rings, what is an example of an epimorphism that is not a retraction?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory

It seems to me that if you have a epimorphism $f:R\to S$ , then $f$ is surjective.

I want to show that there is no $g:S\to R$ such that $f \circ g = 1_S$. But could we not define $g$ to be a constant map sending every element in $S$ to the element $r$ in $R$ such that $f(r) = 1_S$ thus finding the homomorphism we need, and showing that $f$ is indeed a retraction?

Comment: The constant map you're thinking to is not a ring homomorphism; if $f$ is injective, for instance, $f(r)=1$ implies $r=1$. The constant map $g(s)=1$ is a ring homomorphism if and only if $R$ is the zero ring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(All my rings are unital, and all my ring homomorphisms preserve $1$.)

As Giorgio explains, not every epimorphism in $\mathbf{Ring}$ is a surjective homomorphism. Furthermore, its *also* the case that not every surjective homomorphism of rings is a retraction.

To see this, use:

> **Proposition.** Let $n$ denote a non-zero natural number. Then there is no ring homomorphism $$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}.$$

Trivially, this implies that the projection $$\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$$ does not have a section $$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}.$$

In other words, the projection $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not a retraction.

*Proof of proposition.* Suppose for a contradiction that that $f : \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is a ring homomorphism. Then $\mathrm{img}(f)$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Z}$. But since $n$ is non-zero, hence the domain of $f$ is finite. Thus $\mathrm{img}(f)$ is finite. So we deduce there exists a subring of $\mathbb{Z}$ that is finite. But since $\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite, we deduce in particular that there exists a subring of $\mathbb{Z}$ that is distinct from $\mathbb{Z}$.

But this contradicts the fact that the only subring of $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ itself.

Comment: How does proving $\pi_n$ does not have a section the same as proving it does not have a retraction? If say $\pi_n:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ could we not define a $g: \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that $g(x) = 1$ so $\pi_n \circ g = 1_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}$

Comment: @ElBones02 There are no ring homomorphisms $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$. This is what goblin proved.

Comment: @ElBones02, we want $\pi_n \circ g = \mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}$, not $\pi_n \circ g = 1_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}.$

Comment: @DustanLevenstein, that's a much better way of putting it :)

Comment: @DustanLevenstein So we can say $\pi_n : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} $ is not a retraction since there are no ring homomorphisms between $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: @goblin yes, sorry I meant $\text{id}_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}$ but is this not the same as $1_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}$ ? 

EDIT: or are we looking for the additive identity?

Comment: yes, exactly. There can't be a one-sided inverse if there isn't even a map going the other direction.

Answer (score 8):

For start it isn't always the case that an epimorphism is surjective, at least in $\mathbf{Ring}$.

A counterexample is given by the canonical embedding of $i \colon \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Q$. This mapping is an epimorphism because for every pair $f,g \colon \mathbb Q \to L$ if $f \circ i=g \circ i$ then by the *universal property* of $i$ (or if you prefer since $\mathbb Q$ is the field of fraction for $\mathbb Z$) it follows that $f=g$, but $i$ is not a surjective mapping.

Comment: More strongly, there is at most one embedding of $\mathbb Q$ into any other ring $L$.

Comment: that makes sense. In **Ring**, are there surjective maps that are not retractions?

Comment: @HaloLikeAHat there are many indeed: consider for instance the canonical projection $\pi \colon \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, which is clearly surjective. This mapping has no left inverse, otherwise $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ should be (isomorphic) to a subring(and so to a subgroup) of $\mathbb Z$ which is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, for any multiplicative set in a ring $R$, the canonical morphism $R\longrightarrow S^{-1}R$ is a (flat) epimorphism.

It is known that if $f\colon R\longrightarrow S $ is a *finite* epimorphism, then $f$ is surjective.

Also:

- a flat, local epimorphism between local rings is surjective.
- if $R$ is artinian, an epimorphism $f\colon R\longrightarrow S $ is surjective

An example of an epimorphism that is useful for many counter-examples is the canonical map:
$$R\longrightarrow R_s\times R/sR\quad (s\in R)$$
where $R_s$ denotes the ring of fractions with denominator some $s^k$.

If you can read (mathematical) French, there was a most interesting seminar of Pierre Samuel during the academic year 1967-1968 centred on ring epimorphisms available [here](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/feuilleter?id=SAC_1967-1968__2_).